# Uncaught Error: Syntax Error, unrecognized expression: a##toc0

Tags: javascript, expression

Muy buenas,

Al pulsar en un hipervínculo, cuya función es mostrar datos en la parte superior de la web, me salta un error en consola relacionado con una expresión ***(a##toc0)***.

He buscado y probado varias soluciones que aparecen en la web, pero realmente sigo sin entender el por qué de este error y cual sería la posible solución.

***Este es el error que aparece en la consola del navegador:***

```
jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a##toc0
at Function.se.error (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2)
at se.tokenize (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2)
at se.select (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2)
at Function.se (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2)
at Function.s.find (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=3.3.2:2)
at S.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2)
at s.fn.init.S.fn.init (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2)
at new s.fn.init (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=3.3.2:2)
at S (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2)
at displaySection (jquery.toc.js?ver=5.8:26)
```

***Y dónde he visto que aparece esa expresión, es en la siguiente línea de código:***

```js
function hideContainer() {
    $('div.mCSB_container').find('*').css({display:'none'});//, opacity:'0'}, 2000);
  }
  function displaySection(el)
{   
        hideContainer();
        getAllBetween($('a#'+el.attr('href')),$('a#toc'+(parseInt(el.attr('href').split('toc')[1])+1)));
}
```

***¿Alguien podría explicarme una posible solución a esta problema, por favor?***

PD: Siento si no he estructurado bien el mensaje, pero soy novato en esta web.

¡Saludos!

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. El código debe ir en formato texto. Por favor haz clic en [edit] y cambia las imágenes por texto. Saludos

Comment: Buenos días Mauricio, ya he cambiado las imágenes por el código correspondiente. ¡Saludos!

Comment: Sin ver tu código HTML, se me ocurre que esta parte: `('a#'+el.attr('href')` sea la que causa el problema. Tal vez el atributo `href` del elemento tiene un carácter `#`, al concatenar esto con la cadena `a#` se produce el error que muestras en el mensaje. Te sugiero que hagas la depuración de tus variables para que las puedas usar correctamente. Saludos